# How to build an ibeacon backend panel?

Tags: android, backend, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I developed an ibeacon android app and now I am going to extend my app to have website login and back-end control panel in order to user be able to manage its beacons.
Can everyone tell me what is the best way doing that?

Comment: What do you want this back-end control panel to be able to do?  What actions would you perform that constitutes managing its beacons?

Comment: back-end should be able to add or delete beacons, put photo and notification messages they want others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacon can not communicate with your back-end to receive the attachments but your mobile app does. To understand the entire scenario, you gotta try Google proximity Beacons API.

**Step 1:**

> *Adding attachments to your beacon through Google Proximity Beacon API*.

Register your Beacon through [Google Proximity Beacon API.](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides?hl=en) You gotta register your beacon, if you wish add attachments to them. Also do remember that you gotta change the UUID of beacon, if you are willing to register through Google Proximity Beacon API because Beacon database is global. If its Eddystone, change the UID. Once if it is registered, you can actually be able to add attachments to them. Do research on Google Proximity beacon API and revert back to me if you need any clarification while trying to add attachments to the beacons. You can call this app as Beacon Manager Application since it lets you to add attachments.

**Second:**

> *Receiving attachments using Nearby Messages API*

Now that we have added attachments to our beacons using Google Proximity beacons API but to receive the attachments ,we gotta  use [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/). So once if you go near the beacon which has got its attachments registered through Google Proximity Beacon API, it will receive the corresponding attachments automatically.

Try to understand the entire process overflow behind Google Proximity Beacon API [Attachment adder] and Nearby Messages API[Attachments Receiver]. Then you can actually be able to simulate the same while you are trying to build your own back-end. If you've any query, do revert back. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can  build the back-end using any of the web-technology that you love. Before going about building the back-end, its good for you to practice Google Proximity beacon API, Google Nearby Messages API so you will get a strong understanding about what are all the features that your back-end should necessarily have. First and foremost stuff is that you need to provide the user a provision to authenticate their app to use your back-end. Then the authenticated user must be able to register their beacon with your back-end. Next, you should also deal with Entry and exit events. I suggest you to use the library called  Volley for hitting the server. Finally , you should provide campaign management feature where the user could actually be able to publish their Advertisements. Hence its a good practice for you to try using Google Proximity Beacon API and Nearby Messages API to gain a rough idea about building the back-end. Then you can go about pursuing the idea to build something constructive. Hope it helps!!!...

Comment: thanks Stanly for the great answer , just one, the concept of attachments is kind of blurry for me , how it is possible to send 1031 Bytes of data from beacon? @Stanly Moses

Comment: Are you  going to configure the beacon to emit 1031 bytes of data? or Are asking about the attachments? say clearly

Comment: I am asking about the attachment.@stanly Moses

Comment: Check the answer that I have posted.